# Postgresql returned timestamp format differes from test and prod db?

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

I have a column called `start_date` in table X.

In my php project, when I use a simple `select * from table x where id = 1` to retrieve a row from table X in my test DB, the following is returned:

```
{"id":1,"start_date":"2017-12-05 18:56:07"}
```

Now when I do the same in my production database the following is returned:

```
{"id":1,"start_date":"05\/12\/2017 18:56:07"
```

Both my databases have the same `datestyle` which I have set to `ISO,DMY` using

```
ALTER DATABASE xx SET datestyle TO ISO, DMY;
```

Why if both of these settings are the same and my production db is a restore of my test db, are these two queries returning different formats?

Edit: I'm using codeigniters query builder in my php project to retrieve the values from the db. I then view the value of the direct result using `var_dump`.  Here is my php codeigniter method:

```
  function get_last($id) {
    $this->db->where ( "id", $id);      
    return $this->db->get ('table_x')->row_array ();
  }
```

If I replace the function with the following it works, but I would still like to know why the top is returning two different results.

```
  function get_last($id) {
    $this->db->select("id, to_char(dataman, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as start_date");
    $this->db->where ( "id", $id);      
    return $this->db->get ('table_x')->row_array ();
  }
```

This also makes me believe even more that postgregsql is the reason the format is coming back different since by directly defining the format  works.

Comment: maybe you have user settings?.. or session or even transaction?.. second is definetely `SQL` not `ISO` both test and prod databases are xx - right?..

Comment: No database query except for one using `to_json()` or such, where conversion to JSON (and thus, to string) happens inside the DB engine, will ever output a date as a string. The conversion is happening on the client side - in your PHP application. Please provide the relevant details about that, or code.

Comment: please populate the result of `select *,current_setting('datestyle') from table x where id = 1`

Comment: @AlexanderMP, Im using the code igniter framework to manage my db queries.  I will take a look to see if that might be altering the dates.  Also, so what your saying is that when the query is returned, it is received as a date object and the client is converting it to a string?

Comment: @VaoTsun all columns return ISO,DMY.

Comment: Can you maybe run a query directly, through `psql`?

Comment: @AlexanderMP, trough psql it shows the correct value.  And if a do for example `to_char(start_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as start_date`, from inside my php project without altering anything else, it returns the correct format.  Thats another reason why i think it might not be in the php project.  Im using `var_dump` to display the result value.